# Objective-c get day of week in number starting with Monday, NOT Sunday

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, dayofweek

I'm making my custom calendar view for an app for the European market. In a function I should get number of day of week... I do, but it returns the number of the day of week starting with Sunday. How should I hardcode returning this number starting with Monday?
Thanks
Here is what I have so far:

```
-(int)getWeekDay:(NSDate*)date_
{
    NSLocale *frLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setLocale:frLocale];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date_];
    int weekday = [comps weekday];

    NSLog(@"Week day is %i", weekday);
    return weekday;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use `[NSCalendar setFirstWeekday:]`, as Joshua said in his answer.

Otherwise, you can do integer arithmetic. Vova's method is straightforward:

```
if (weekday>1)
    weekday--; 
else 
    weekday=7;
```

This one below works too, although it's a bit confusing:

```
int europeanWeekday = ((weekday + 5) % 7) + 1;
```

Comment: Well, and it won't depend on System Local Settings?

Comment: Yes, the better solution will be using conditions if(weekday>1) { weekday--; } else weekday=7;

Comment: Thanks @yAak; fixed my answer. Vova: no, did read the `NSDateComponents` documentation on `weekDay`? "Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1." Since you're using a specific calendar instead of using the system calendar, you'll always get the same result.

Comment: That reduces to europeanWeekday = weekday ... :[  i was just fiddling with this on paper too, so dont feel bad, haha.

Comment: Un-downvoted since you fixed!  However, Joshua's answer to use `[NSCalendar setFirstWeekday:...]` is probably the best for others coming to this topic.

Comment: Thanks, and agreed. I had upvoted Joshua's answer already, but I'll edit my answer to mention `setFirstWeekday` as well.

Comment: `NSCalendar`'s `firstWeekday` property [is ignored by the `NSDateComponents`' `weekday` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022360/865175).

Answer (score 9):

You should use [`[NSCalendar setFirstWeekday:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/setFirstWeekday%3a) to do this.